# meteor for(let x of y) not translated by ecmascript

Tags: javascript, android, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have an app that produces an error on *some* devices / browsers (noticed e.g. on Android default browser.

After a while of debugging I noticed that some ES6 code seems to slip through to the generated JS:

```
Template.updateAccountModalInner.helpers({
  notAllEmailsVerified: function () {
    const user = Session.get('userInScope');
    if (!user || !user.emails) {
        return null;
    }
    for(let email of user.emails) {
        if (!email.verified) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
},
```

And although I use the ecmascript Package (ecmascript@0.7.3, ecmascript-runtime@0.3.15) the "for(let email of user.emails)" stays in the generated file.

In package.json I have:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2"
  }
```

Is this syntax correct? Do I need to enable ES& for JS files? ...?

https://docs.meteor.com/packages/ecmascript.html#Usage

Comment: IDEA suggests that I convert a for(var x of y) to for(let x of y) ...

Comment: Do you have `ecmascript` package installed? And what is `user.emails`? Is it array or object?

Comment: Yes, ecmascript@0.7.3 is installed. user.emails is an array.

Comment: Ugh, I don't know why you have issues exactly on Android. I encourage you trying `some`. Replace your loop with `return user.emails.some(email => !email.verified)` and delete `return false`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that reads nicer anyway. I'll try this.